# PHP check whether line number x exists

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, lines

Is there any way to check whether line exists? If line exists then read it

My code

```
<?php
$s = 7; //$_POST['s'];
$file = fopen("text.txt","r");
$lines = file("text.txt");
echo $lines[$s];
fclose($file);
?>
```

text.txt contains only 6 lines so it returns - Undefined offset: 7

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/isset

Comment: Unrelated note: [`file()`](http://php.net/file) works out of the box and loads the contents of the file split by newlines directly into an array — you don't need to `fopen` the file.

Comment: That does not even remotely apply to this question.

Comment: ... but is still good advice

Comment: so without $file = fopen("text.txt","r"); ?

Comment: @user3371881: That was meant as a sidenote and not related to the actual issue. Please see [John's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22359766/1438393) below to know how to actually solve your problem.

Comment: yes ok ... i asked just to make code easier ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$s = 7 - 1; // Arrays are zero-based in PHP
$lines = file("text.txt");
if (count($lines) >= $s) {
  // you're good
}
```

or:

```
$s = 7 - 1; // Arrays are zero-based in PHP
$lines = file("text.txt");
if (isset($lines[$s])) {
  // you're good
}
```